# Enforce that a Grape Entity always returns an array?

Tags: ruby, mongoid, ruby-grape

How can I enforce that my Grape Entity always returns an array (collection) even if its just a singular object? I have heard that some people create a helper method that gets called inside their endpoint, but I have not found any examples of anyone doing that, online.

The default functionality of an Entity is that it returns an object if only a single document (mongoid object) is returned. If a collection of documents is returned then it returns an array, I dont want my client application having to do a check every time to see if an object or an array got returned from my API.

```
## Resource (HTTP Endpoint)
desc 'List departments a user can and cannot access'
params do
  requires :user_id
end
get :department_access do
  @user = BACKBONE::User.find(@access_key.user_id)
  requires_admin!
  user = BACKBONE::User.find(params[:user_id])
  can_access = BACKBONE::Department.user_can_access(user)
  no_access = BACKBONE::Department.user_cannot_access(user)
  present_success can_access
  present :can_access, can_access, with: BACKBONE::Entities::DepartmentBase
  present :no_access, no_access, with: BACKBONE::Entities::DepartmentBase
end
```

-

```
## Entity
module BACKBONE
  module Entities
    class DepartmentBase < BACKBONE::Entities::Mongoid
      expose :name
      expose :prefix
      with_options(format_with: :mongo_id) do
        expose :company_id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

JSON Response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "request_time": 0.009812,
    "records": 1,
    "can_access": {
        "id": "59699d1a78cee4f8d07528fc",
        "created_at": "2017-07-14T21:42:02.666-07:00",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-14T21:42:02.666-07:00",
        "name": "Tenant Improvement",
        "prefix": "CACC",
        "company_id": "596927fb670f6eec21c4f409"
    },
    "no_access": {
        "id": "59699cca78cee4f8d07528fb",
        "created_at": "2017-07-14T21:40:42.005-07:00",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-14T21:40:42.005-07:00",
        "name": "Field Operations",
        "prefix": "CACC",
        "company_id": "596927fb670f6eec21c4f409"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a coworker and I came up with a solution with a helper, create a helper method that always returns an array:

```
def present_array(key, data, entity)
  d = (data.class.respond_to? :count) ? [data] : data
  d = [] if d.nil?
  present key, d, entity
end
```